# Laravel access method without controller name

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a CI user now moving on to Laravel. Regarding routing, how do I make a method accessible via the method name alone for instance:

```
/controller/mymethod
```

becomes accessible as

```
/mymethod
```

In short I'm looking for the Laravel equivalent of CI's

```
$route['(method1|method2)'] = 'controller/$1';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register a single `GET` route.

```
Route::get('method', 'controller@method');
```

You can create more complex routes to match multiple methods using back references.

```
Route::get('(method1|method2|method3)', 'controller@(:1)');
```

In **Laravel 4** you take a different approach. You would instead register the controller itself with the router, and list the URI for it to respond to as `/`.

```
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

This `HomeController` would then contain methods prefixed with the HTTP verb you want them to respond to.

```
class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return 'Home Page';
    }

    public function getAbout()
    {
        return 'About Page';
    }

}
```

The `getIndex` method will respond to root requests, e.g., `localhost/your-project/public`. All other requests will be something like `localhost/your-project/public/about`, etc.